# Show negative downvotes in the top bar

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, top-bar

When I gain reputation, the `topbar-icon` will show the reputation addition:

> [image: Image 1]

---

However, when I lose reputation, why doesn't the top bar show it?

Would it be feasible to show it? (Example below)

> [image: Image 2]

---

**Update:**

It might be a bug.

**Browser**: Safari Version 10.0

**OS**: macOS Sierra 10.12

Comment: The top bar *does* show rep loss, exactly how you described (at least for me).  What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: @NobodyNada It does? I've never seen it before, maybe it's a bug (I'm using Safari)

Comment: @NobodyNada But this post also states that it doesn't show -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208900/display-lost-negative-reputation-in-topbar-achievements

Comment: Oh.  I was sure I saw it, but maybe I'm just imagining it.  Sorry!

Comment: @NobodyNada i don't recall seeing it showing negative amounts. if i got -2  as the only item for the day i see nothing, i only notice deductions after positive rep changes (ie. i get +15 then -2 it shows +13). though i do recall once upon a time seeing negative amounts but never recently (like in the past year)